# When tunnelling, what happens when the cards drawn do not match those played?

Tags: ticket-to-ride-europe

In Ticket to Ride Europe, when I plan to build on top of tunnels, what happens when none of the drawn cards match the colours I have in hand?  For example,

```
Tunnel length: 3 grey segments
Played cards: 3 red cards
Drawn cards: 3 blue cards
```

What additional cards am I supposed to play in the above case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If none of the drawn cards match the colour of the cards you chose to play, then you are in luck - the tunnel does not cost *any* additional cards. To put it another way, the tunnel costs 0 additional cards. This case isn't explicitly discussed in the rules, but I think it's quite clear.

> When attempting to claim a Tunnel route, a player first lays down the number of cards required by the length of the route. Then the three top cards from the Train draw pile are turned face-up. For each card revealed whose colour matches the colour of the cards played to claim the Tunnel, an additional card of the same colour (or a Locomotive) must now be played from his hand. Only then can the player successfully claim the Tunnel route.

Comment: I'd say it's pretty explicit. Paraphrasing for brevity: _For each matching card, you must play an additional card to claim the route._ If there are zero matching cards, you must play zero additional cards.